# Show loading indicator at root level until all route resolves are complete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I've been doing some Googling around this already but I'm unable to find a solution that works.

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.5 and .NET Web API 2 to build a web application and I would quite simply like to hide the `ng-view` element until all resolves have completed on the route.

I'm trying to use the `$routeChangeStart` and `$routeChangeSuccess` to set a variable on the `$rootScope` that is used in the index html to display the loading indicator and hide the content until the variable is `false`.

Here is my routing code for the routeChange properties:

```
_app.config([
        '$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$provide',
        function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $provide) {
                    $routeProvider.when('/Account',
                    {
                        templateUrl: '/Content/js/areas/account/account.html',
                        controller: 'accountController',
                        resolve: {
                            $accountResolver: function (accountService) {
                                return accountService.getMyAccountData();
                            }
                        },
                        caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                    });
            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '404' });

        }
]);

_app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$window', '$q', 'authService',
        function ($rootScope, $location, $window, $q, authService) {
            $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart",
                function (e, curr, prev) {
                    $rootScope.$loadingRoute = true;
                });
            $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess",
                function (evt, next) {
                    $rootScope.$loadingRoute = false;
                });
            $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError",
                function (evt, next) {
                    $rootScope.$loadingRoute = false;
                });
        }]);
```

And here is my html using that `$loadingRoute` variable:

```
<body class="ng-cloak" data-ng-app="wishlist" data-ng-controller="appController">
    <wl-header></wl-header>
    <preloader ng-if="$loadingRoute"></preloader>
    <section ng-view ng-if="!$loadingRoute" class="container ng-cloak"></section>
</body>
```

I understand that there's quite a lot of articles covering this but none seem to work in my case. `$loadingRoute` gets set to true when the route change starts, as expected, which I will see if I add `{{$loadingRoute}}` to the HTML before the `<section></section>` tag. However before the `$accountResolver`is resolved, the `$routeChangeSuccess` gets fired, setting `$rootScope.$loadingRoute = false` which is unexpected.

I was under the impression that `$routeChangeSuccess` only got fired after all resolves had completed on the current route.

Am I doing something really obviously wrong here? Or has Angular simply changed?

Edit: I would also like to add that this approach worked in previous projects, so I'm at a real loss as to what's going wrong. I *could* set `$rootScope.$loadingRoute` manually in each page controller but that feels too dirty and unmaintainable.

Edit 2:

```
_app.factory('accountService', [
        'accountResource',
        function (accountResource) {
            var _self = this;

            return {
                register: function (authData) {
                    return accountResource.register(authData);
                },

                getMyAccountData: function () {
                    return accountResource.getMyAccountData();
                }
            }
        }
]);

_app.factory('accountResource', [
        '$resource', 'rootUrl',
        function ($resource, rootUrl) {
            var api = rootUrl() + 'api/Account';
            return $resource(api,
            {},
            {
                register: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '{0}/register'.format(api)
                },
                getMyAccountData: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '{0}/GetMyAccountData'.format(api)
                }
            });
        }
    ])
```

Comment: If this does not work, then you did something wrong. There's too much code that is relevant but is not posted. Where are accountService and accountController?

Comment: AccountController is irrelevant in this situation because any code inside the controller will run after the resolves. As for the service, it's returning `accountResource.getMyAccountData()` which is a very simple Angular $resource call to a Get method. In short, it returns a promise that resolves after the Web API has returned a response. The `$routeChangeSuccess` is firing before the promise has resolved, which I think is incorrect. If you would really like to see the few lines of code in the service and resource I can share them..

Comment: There's no evidence that getMyAccountData really returns a promise. The thing you're describing is possible if it doesn't return a promise, and it is very unlikely that it may happen otherwise. Please, provide all the relevant code and consider adding a plunk/fiddle that can replicate the issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've updated the question to include the service and resource, but I don't have time to setup a plunkr/fiddle tonight, I'll try and get one up sometime tomorrow though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a resolver to delay route change, it should return a promise. Otherwise route change happens immediately, this is what happens when `$routeChangeSuccess` is triggered before a promise from `accountService.getMyAccountData()` is resolved.

The problem is `$resource` methods (and so `accountService.getMyAccountData()`) return self-filling object that is populated with data asynchronously. A promise for this data is available as `$promise` property (see [the reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)), so it should be used for a resolver:

```
$accountResolver: function (accountService) {
  return accountService.getMyAccountData().$promise;
}
```

If `accountService` is supposed to be purely promise-based wrapper for `accountResource`, a cleaner way to do this is to return a promise from its methods instead:

```
getMyAccountData: function () {
    return accountResource.getMyAccountData().$promise;
}
```

Comment: My issue was indeed that I wasn't returning the `$promise` in the service. I thought it would be something small that I missed, thanks for your clarification!